# Paley-Zygmund inequality.

Tags: probability-theory

I was trying to understand the proof of the Paley-Zygmund inequality, but encountered the following step, which is not clear for me, i.e.
$$\mathbb{E}(X\cdot \ \mathbb{1}_{X < \lambda\mathbb{E}(X)}) \leq \lambda\cdot \mathbb{E}(X)$$
Sorry for this "brilliant" question, but I would really appreciate if someone can elaborate on this.

Comment: Since you have $1_{\{X < \lambda \mathbb E[X]\}}$ you're integrating on the set where $X$ is lower than $\lambda \mathbb E[X]$. Hence you have inequality $\mathbb E[X1_{\{X < \lambda \mathbb E[X]\}}] < \mathbb E[\lambda \mathbb E[X] 1_{\{X < \lambda \mathbb E[X]\}}]$. Now use linearity of expectation and fact that indicator function is less or equal to $1$ to conclude.

Comment: But what if the random variable is discrete?

Comment: What does it change, Patrik? You still have pointwise inequality of type $X < \lambda \mathbb E[X]$ on the set you're integrating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$X1_{X <\lambda \mathbb E X} \leq \lambda (\mathbb EX) 1_{X <\lambda \mathbb EX}$. Now take expectation on both sides and use the fact that $P(X <\lambda \mathbb E X) \leq 1$

Note that  the following is also correct:

$X1_{X \leq \lambda \mathbb E X} \leq \lambda (\mathbb EX) 1_{X \leq \lambda \mathbb EX}$; take expectation on both sides and use the fact that $P(X \leq \lambda \mathbb E X) \leq 1$ to get $\mathbb E X1_{X \leq \lambda \mathbb E X} \leq \lambda (\mathbb EX)$.

Comment: why the first inequality has $X < \lambda (\mathbb{E}X)$?

Comment: @Patrik $<$ and $\leq $ are both fine. I typed $<$ because that is what you have in your question.

Comment: No, I am not assuming that